# Как отключить контекстное меню у тега HTML5 video?

Tags: javascript, html5, видео

У меня реализован live стрим видео webm с использованием MediaSourceExtensions API на стороне JavaScript. Тег `video` создаётся без контролов, но по клику правой кнопкой мыши по области видео можно показать контролы, промотать видео, развернуть на весь экран...

Мне этого не надо - пользователю веб-приложения должны быть доступны только те функции, которые я запрограммирую, и не более. **Как отключить это контекстное меню тега `video`?**

Если это невозможно, может помимо `video` можно ещё как-нибудь рендерить контент MSE? Может на `canvas`?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Первый вариант**

Используем JavaScript

```js
document.getElementById("id1").oncontextmenu = function (e) {
    return false;
};
```

```html
<div>без меню</div>
<div><img id="id1" src="http://www.2fons.ru/pic/201503/1280x1024/2fons.ru-84831.jpg" width="300"></div><br>

<div>c меню</div>
<div><img id="id2" src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/208/421162-svetik.jpg" width="300"></div>
```

Данный пример сделан с изображением но для видео он тоже сработает, так как отключает контекстное меню на любом элементе.

**Второй вариант**

Поверх видео положить прозрачную картинку.

**Третий вариант**

Чистый HTML (почти)

```html
<img oncontextmenu='return false;' src="http://www.2fons.ru/pic/201503/1280x1024/2fons.ru-84831.jpg" />
```

Comment: Ну да, всё гениальное просто. )) Использую сразу оба варинта, повесив на прозрачный слой свой функционал. Спасибо!